# Volume within parameter space

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Imagine a parameter space with variable `0<p<1`, `0<e1<1/2` and `0<e2<1/2`.

There are certain conditions on the parameters in some situations. For example `p<e1` or `(p)(e1)/((p)(e1)+(1-p)(1-e2))<e1/e2`

How can I determine the volume of the parameter space which satisfies these (and other) conditions?

I would like to determine them algebraically, and not via a numerical simulation of plotting points within parameter space. I also do not want to solve any complex equations myself. I simply want a function which gives me the result easily. Does this exist?

Update:
The suggestion below works very well in many cases, however, I seem to have hit a problem.

Try to evaluate: `NIntegrate[Boole[0<p<1&&0<e1<1/2&&0<e2<1/2&&e1<e2&&0<e3<1/2&&0<(e3-e2 e3-e1 p-e3 p+e1 e3 p+e2 e3 p)/((1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3) (-1+p))<1&&0<(-e1+e1 e3+e2 e3)/(1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3)<1&&40/100<(((e3-e2 e3-e1 p-e3 p+e1 e3 p+e2 e3 p)/((1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3) (-1+p)))(e3+p-2 e3 p)+(1-((e3-e2 e3-e1 p-e3 p+e1 e3 p+e2 e3 p)/((1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3) (-1+p))))(1-e3))],{p,0,1},{e1,0,1/2},{e2,0,1/2},{e3,0,1/2},WorkingPrecision->20]`

This gives something like 0.036.

Try now to weaken the condition by lowering 50/100 to 40/100. The results becomes 0....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could integrate over the region, using [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Boole.html):

```
Integrate[
 Boole[0 < p < 1 && 0 < e1 < 1/2 && 0 < e2 < 1/2 &&
   (p < e1 || (p) (e1)/((p) (e1) + (1 - p) (1 - e2)) < e1/e2)],
 {p, 0, 1}, {e1, 0, 1/2}, {e2, 0, 1/2}]

(* 1/16 (5 - 6 Log[2] + 2 Log[4]) *)
```

Comment: It would be good to stress that this is *the standard* way to input these types of problems in Mathematica and that it is also supported by `NIntegrate`.  What I mean is that `NIntegrate` does actually know what `Boole` is and won't sample points outside of that region if avoidable.  It doesn't treat it as a numerical black box.

Comment: It might also be worth stressing that success in a particular case depends on the success of `Integrate`/`NIntegrate` in handling that case.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again, I seem to have run into some trouble.

`NIntegrate[Boole[0<p<1&&0<e1<1/2&&0<e2<1/2&&e1<e2&&0<e3<1/2&&0<(e3-e2 e3-e1 p-e3 p+e1 e3 p+e2 e3 p)/((1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3) (-1+p))<1&&0<(-e1+e1 e3+e2 e3)/(1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3)<1&&50/100<(((e3-e2 e3-e1 p-e3 p+e1 e3 p+e2 e3 p)/((1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3) (-1+p)))(e3+p-2 e3 p)+(1-((e3-e2 e3-e1 p-e3 p+e1 e3 p+e2 e3 p)/((1-e1-2 e3+e1 e3+e2 e3) (-1+p))))(1-e3))],{p,0,1},{e1,0,1/2},{e2,0,1/2},{e3,0,1/2},WorkingPrecision->20]`

Try lowering the 50/100 and see what happens... Output is now 0 for a weaker condition...

Comment: General tip: When an integral seems hard for *Mathematica*, first try making it easier.  For instance, leave `WorkingPrecision` at `MachinePrecision`; instead set `AccuracyGoal -> 6` and `PrecisionGoal -> 6` or some such lower value.  At least if it doesn't work (it doesn't), it should take less time.  Second, try `red = Reduce[expr, {p, e1, e2, e3}, Reals]` and `NIntegrate[red,...]`.  It works, but `Reduce` takes 90 sec. on my machine.   Third, you might try `Integrate[expr,...] /. Integrate -> NIntegrate`.  It takes about 48 sec.  Of course, sometimes the solution is to increase precision.